# Can I allow tkinter's mainloop() and GLUT's glutMainLoop() run concurrently?

Tags: python, c++, opengl, tkinter, glut

I am writing a python tkinter application that interfaces with a C++ library that I am also writing. The C++ library contains a class that wraps some of GLUT's functions.

My main function (python) looks something like this:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import myCustomCppLibrary

#This sets up the GLUT bindings.
myCustomCppLibrary.Initialize()

root = tk.Tk()
# ... some stuff

#Something in mainloop() eventually calls glutMainLoop()
root.mainloop()
myCustomCppLibrary.Finalize()
sys.exit(0)
```

Unfortunately, `glutMainLoop` blocks `root.mainloop()`, meaning that my tkinter GUI becomes unfunctional as soon as my GLUT window is launched.

I did try to add a `std::thread` object to my wrapper class but `glutMainLoop` appears to exit the entire process after exiting, meaning that running it in a thread is not conducive to a clean exit.

I was thinking that I could use GLUT's `atexit` to signal to tkinter that it needs to close and join the thread, but ideally the process would not end when I close the GLUT window (I don't think this would give a clean exit either).

Is is possible to have these two loops run concurrently, and to do so cleanly?

I would like to avoid modifying GLUT's source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix GLUT with other windowing frameworks. At least not without going through a lot of pain. But one has to wonder: What is there in GLUT that you *must* use it? With a little extra module you can create an OpenGL context within TkInter [Tkinter OpenGL context in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844882/tkinter-opengl-context-in-python)

Comment: Interesting, I will certainly look into this. I require access to the underlying opengl resources (I am binding a CUDA array to an opengl texture) so hopefully that is something I can do with this.

Comment: @wvn: … but how does that make you depend on GLUT? Answer: It doesn't! – GLUT is just some "random" framework out there. Originally created to faciliate quick-and-dirty OpenGL tinkering programs.

Comment: You are certainly correct that I am bound in no way to GLUT. I was using that simply because I have another application that does something similar, so I went for familiarity. My concern now is that if I run my OpenGL context through Togl that I will need to access low-level resources in my external C++/CUDA library. For someone as unfamiliar with OpenGL as I, that will be a challenge. Either way, probably worth learning.

Comment: @wvn: As far as GLUT vs. Togl goes with respect to CUDA: There is zero difference. OpenGL is pretty much a "What You See Is What You Use" API. There's no "hidden", low level stuff going on. A OpenGL context is created using a windowing system specific API (usually wrapped in a framework) and from there on, that's it. GLUT does nothing "special" to faciliate CUDA (heck development of the original GLUT ceded long before CUDA was on the horizon).

Comment: Having taken a second look at the source from one of my old GLUT projects it actually seems as though doing what I need will not be difficult. I recall that OpenGL is state-based so I assume that I can simply create and bind textures as long as it all happens within the same process. I think the way forward here is clear now. I appreciate the input.